# Facing issues when writing conditions in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the records based on precedence priority(b.precedence ). IF precedence 1 is available get the corresponding row . If there is no records for precedence 1 go for next precedence. how to write the conditions in SQL. Below is the query i have written for Precedence 1. Please help on this

```
SELECT 
    b.precedence, b.template_code, a.CLASS, a.seat_number, 
    int_row_pos, int_column_pos, deck_name, control_attribute
FROM 
    sat_seat_number_tmp a, sat_ssr_seat b
WHERE
    a.bd_airport_code = 'GNR'
    AND a.off_airport_code = 'TMP'
    AND a.child_bd_airport_code = 'GNR'
    AND a.child_off_airport_code = 'TMP'
    AND a.CLASS = 'ECONOMY'
    AND a.seat_number MEMBER OF getSeats(
                               v_seatRange => '3A'
                             )
    AND (b.precedence = 1 AND b.SEG_CONNECTION = 'Y')
```

### sat_ssr_seat Table

[enter image description here][1]

for Precedence there is no record exists consider using precedence2

The Current results for precedence 1 is
[enter image description here][2]

if there is no record exists for precedence1 then check if any record for precedence 2. This one how can i add into query

Comment: Optionally: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Please user proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 30 years!!!

Comment: Please read this on a guide how to ask a proper question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: Please rewrite your query with a proper join. Are you cross joining the two tables? They don't seem related in your query. And please show sample data for both tables and the expected result, so we see what you are after.

Comment: HI Thorsten 
The above is query already exists in procedure . I Have added extra where condition for precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does that "precedence" come from?

This is how I understood the question:

- properly join these two tables; as commented, looks like they are cross joined in your query
- if precedence is suppose to be the *lowest* for that particular `some_id_column` (or maybe some other value; can't tell), then one obvious & simple option is to use a subquery to fetch it. There may be other, better options, but - as I said - that's how I understood it and posted something that *might* be on the right track

---

```
SELECT 
    b.precedence, b.template_code, a.CLASS, a.seat_number, 
    int_row_pos, int_column_pos, deck_name, control_attribute
FROM 
    sat_seat_number_tmp a join sat_ssr_seat b on a.some_id_column = b.some_id_column
WHERE   a.bd_airport_code = 'GNR'
    AND a.off_airport_code = 'TMP'
    AND a.child_bd_airport_code = 'GNR'
    AND a.child_off_airport_code = 'TMP'
    AND a.CLASS = 'ECONOMY'
    AND a.seat_number MEMBER OF getSeats(
                               v_seatRange => '3A'
                             )
    AND b.SEG_CONNECTION = 'Y'
    AND b.precedence = (select min(x.precedence)
                        from sat_ssr_seat x
                        where x.some_id_column = b.some_id_column
                       )
```

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot for your Answer . I will check this one